# ActiveX not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

I'm currently developing a web based scanning application. I am using [twainDotNet](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet) to get and fire scanner events. The process is done through an ActiveX control. My ActiveX control works well in IE 10 for Windows 8, but it is not working for IE 11 on Windows 8.1, but it shows on the ManageAddOn section of IE

Please help me to solve this problem, if anything is not clear in my description please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe the differences in behavior between IE10 and IE11, so it's hard to guess what's going wrong, but a few points come to mind:

- First and foremost, managed code is [not supported for IE plugins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587(v=vs.85).aspx).  There are several issues involved, but the practical upshot is people in a [place to know](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/04/10/do-not-write-browser-extensions-toolbars-bhos-and-activex-in-managed-dotnet-code.aspx) say you should not use [managed code for plugins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).
- ActiveX controls need to be updated to support enhanced protected mode and other changes to the Windows 8 security model.  It's pretty involved, but the [technical details start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Finally, I'm sure you already know this, but make sure you're testing this on the desktop version of IE, as the Windows Store experience doesn't support [ActiveX controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920753(v=vs.85).aspx), that you've accounted for any of the [potential 32/64-bit issues](http://www.twainforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=10337), and any of the other basics that might come into play.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance